# Boost compile error on converting UUID to string using boost::lexical_cast

Tags: c++, boost, uuid, lexical-cast, boost-uuid

I have this code which is based on several posts in SO:

```
boost::uuids::uuid uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();
auto uuidString= boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(uuid);
```

but when I am compiling this code, I am getting this error:

```
Source type is neither std::ostream`able nor std::wostream`able     C:\Local\boost\boost\lexical_cast\detail\converter_lexical.hpp
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing the include, I guess:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/472d67aa388cdc75)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/random_generator.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::uuids::uuid uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();
    auto uuidString = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(uuid);
}
```

Comment: just to be clear, it's uuid_io.hpp that seems to be necessary for the lexical cast operation, both to and from uuid/string. In my case CLion warns that it's unused, but if you remove it you'll have issues similar to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string       uuidStr;

boost::uuids::uuid uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();

ss << uuid;
ss >> uuidStr;
```

---

The [Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/uuid/uuid.html) states:

> Stream Operators
>
> The standard input and output stream operators << and >> are provided by including boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp. The string representation of a uuid is hhhhhhhh-hhhh-hhhh-hhhh-hhhhhhhhhhhh where h is a hexidecimal digit.

```
boost::uuids::uuid u1; // initialize uuid

std::stringstream ss;
ss << u1;

boost::uuids::uuid u2;
ss >> u2;

assert(u1, u2);
```

However the `lexical_cast` should work as well.

Maybe you should check what `uuid` actually contains to figure out if there's something wrong with the generated `uuid`.

Also:

```
boost::uuids::uuid u; // initialize uuid

std::string s1 = to_string(u);
```

should be slightly faster according to the doc.